# iOS - Managing Core Data with a REST API

Tags: ios, core-data

I’m using a REST API to download my data. Sometimes I try to access a property of the `NSManagedObject`’s subclass, but it doesn’t exist as it isn’t yet downloaded. Should I override the getter in the `NSManagedObject` subclass to go out and fetch the data? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to load all necessary data for your NSManagedObject subclass at once. For instance if you have entity **User** with properties **name** and **age** you should download enough data to create fully initialised object before using it.

If you have complex entity you can split it in to multiple entities and download data for them separately.

Another solution can be to use [NSIncrementalStore](http://nshipster.com/nsincrementalstore/) but it can be daunting and time consuming to implement.